# How to build a last login script using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I create a last login script using php.

Comment: Care to clarify? What in particular is giving your trouble?

Comment: I was wondering how can I go about creating the last login script, for example where should I begin forgive me I'm kind of new to this.

Answer (score 2):

For storing last access time, save the current time against logged in user in database at the end of the script.

For storing last login time, save the current time against verified user after identity confirmation is done.

Suppose you have a `user` table in database which has a `last_login` field, and `$user` array contains identity of the logged-in/verified user identity.

```
// assuming you are using PDO for database access
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET last_login = ? where user_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($user['id']), strftime("%Y-%M-%D"));
```